# Can not see image during server side rendering in django

Tags: html, css, django

I can not see the image during server side rendering in `django`. Any help or hint would be appreciated. Below is the code I have written.

```
{% if object_list %}
{% for post in object_list %}

    <div id="colorlib-main">
      <section class="ftco-section ftco-no-pt ftco-no-pb">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row d-flex">
            <div class="col-xl-8 py-5 px-md-5">
              <div class="row pt-md-4">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="d-md-flex">
                    <a href="single.html" class="img img-2" style="background-image: url({{post.image.url}});"></a>
                    <div class="text text-2 pl-md-4">
                      <h3 class="mb-2"><a href="single.html">{{post.title}}</a></h3>
                      <div class="meta-wrap">
                        <p class="meta">
                          <span><i class="icon-calendar mr-2"></i>June 28, 2019</span>
                          <span><a href="single.html"><i class="icon-folder-o mr-2"></i>Travel</a></span>
                          <span><i class="icon-comment2 mr-2"></i>5 Comment</span>
                        </p>
                      </div>
                      <p class="mb-4">A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia.</p>
                      <p><a href="#" class="btn-custom">Read More <span class="ion-ios-arrow-forward"></span></a></p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>

{% endfor %}

{% else %}
  <p>No post yet!!</p>
{% endif %}
```

Any clue/hint?

Comment: If you look at your HTML source in your browser debugger, what does the `style="..."` attribute show? Also you should see the 404 error in the same debugger.

Comment: The other problem I see is that your `<a>` div doesn't have content, are you setting its height in the `img` or `img-2` css class?

Comment: i use that by default of colorlib template. i think there is no error. some error might be in this line              <a href="single.html" class="img img-2" style="background-image: url({{post.image.url}});"></a>

Comment: As I said, open your browser developer tools. Check two things: Is there an error displayed (File not found error)? And what is the url in your browser (look at the **actual** HTML source code)? Also to be sure, if there aren't any "file not found" errors, check using the CSS debugger the height of the `<a>` element.